# Is percentile a good method?

Tags: spss, quantiles, predictor, binning, dependent-variable

Hello I'm an undergraduate student doing research about prevalence of carpal tunnel syndrome among college students I want to follow the method of this research (prevalence of carpal tunnel syndrome among laboratory workers), to detect the prevalence.

I have an outcome variable called symptom severity scale which we obtained from students using this questionnaire below (the same for the study among laboratory workers):
[image]

Which the total score is obtained from adding together the score of each of the 11 questions (this process was done for each of the 100 student of our study)

Now to determine the prevalence the research among laboratory workers used this method below: and their sample size is 225.

The  outcome  variable was categorized using percentiles to Mild, Moderate, and Severe in the Symptom Severity Scale (SSS). The three categories (mild, moderate, and severe) of susceptibility to having CTS symptoms were based on the SSS. Individuals suspected of having mild CTS symptoms are within the 50th percentile. Individuals suspected of having moderate CTS symptoms are within the 50th-75th percentile. Individuals suspected of having severe CTS symptoms are above the 75th percentile.
And this is the results that they got:
[image]

But is this a good method using percentiles? Because to my understanding they are not taking the actual value of test scores into account, they just used percentiles to make an assumption that for example: those who fall above 75 percentile have severe symptoms. That may not be correct because, maybe the subjects have scores ranging from 13 to 35 and those subject for example scored 33 34 35 and they fall in the severe catagory whearas you can score as 52 53 51 and this maybe considered severe, and not 33 35 or 38, because the score can range from (11 to 55).

There is a method but it's not a standard method for this test it was just suggested by an other as in the image below describes it:
[image]

So my question is: is the method suggested by the author (storey) a good method? Better than percentiles? If not what method should I perform in spss?

And my second question is why the study done on laboratory workers didn't consider the asymptomatic group? (Because if you have a total score of 11 that means it's asymptomatic).

It is because they also considered them to be within the mild catagory Or they didn't have any laboratory worker that was asymptomatic?

Thank you I hope it's cleared explained

I will only use symptom severity scale and not functional status scale.

Comment: I don't think these authors are making assumptions: they are simply declaring that they will *characterize* anyone scoring above the 75th percentile as "severe," *etc.* There's no "right" or "wrong" to this: it's just terminology. Storey's method goes beyond this by using this terminology to draw conclusions. As the text indicates, determining how well this works requires looking at data to assess how accurate those conclusions are likely to be in practice. But your question "is it better than percentiles" is unanswerable, because what you mean by "percentiles" as a decision method is unclear.

Comment: @whuber thank you very much for your answer, sorry I didn't mention this, the authors in the laboratory research use these scores: 1.asymptomatic 2.mild 3. Moderate 4.intense 5. severe. And in the storey method they use these scores: 1.asymptomatic 2. Mild 3.moderate 4. Severe 5. Very severe

Comment: @whuber the largest score that I have is 35 in my own research, in this case is it more accurate to say that 35 lies in the severe group (group 4) using storey method, than to say that 35 lies in the severe group (group 5) using percentiles method?